# How to addclass to a different element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Due to the great help of ori, I've got a script working exactly as I wanted. Unfortunately, due to my own limited jQuery knowledge - I can't get the next phase working!

Now I want to expand it further by assigning a function to a different element if the href matches.

The code that works, and correctly assigns a class is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    var matches;  
   if( matches = location.href.match(/\?(pcat=\w+)/) ) {  
    $('a[href*="' + matches[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
}; 
  });
</script>
```

This will successfully add the class 'active' to the original a href element. What I want to do now is instead of assign the class to the link, is to open accordion menu that contains the href links on page load.

So I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    var matches;  
   if( matches = location.href.match(/\?(pcat=\w+)/) ) {  
    $('a[href*="' + matches[1] + '"]').function() {
        $('p.menuheader').addclass('openheader');}
      );
    }); 

</script>
```

But It doesn't work, I think I've got syntax errors.

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you correctly call `addClass` with a capital `C`.

In your second example you call `addclass` with a lowercase `c` which probably doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `each` and `closest` method to find the containing element. Also change `addclass` to `addClass`.

```
$('a[href*="' + matches[1] + '"]').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('p.menuheader').addClass('openheader');}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that "accordion menu that contains the href links", why just not do like:

```
 $('a[href*="' + matches[1] + '"]').parent().addclass('openheader');
```